# MySQL union query, order by 2 variables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Each table (table1 & table2) has its own DATETIME field.
I'm trying to catch id's of the two tables and order them by their DATETIME field.

Example:

```
Table 1                        Table 2
------------                 -------------
id |  datetime1               id | table1id  | datetime2
------------------------      -----------------------
1  |  2014-09-21 20:31:26     1  | 2         | 2014-09-21 20:31:29
2  |  2014-09-21 20:31:27     2  | 3         | 2014-09-21 20:31:30
3  |  2014-09-21 20:31:28

Table 3                      
------------               
id |  user               
------------------------   
2  |  phil                
3  |  nathalie
```

My output isn't ordered properly with this query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
    1 AS selection, 
    table1.id, table1.datetime1, 
    table2.datetime2 
    table3.user 
    FROM Table1 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 
    ON table1.id = table2.table1id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table3
    ON table1.id = table3.id

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
    2 AS selection, 
    table1.id, table1.datetime1, 
    table2.datetime2 
    table3.user 
    FROM Table1 
    INNER JOIN table2 
    ON table1.id = table2.table1id
    INNER JOIN table3
    ON table1.id = table3.id
) AS query
ORDER BY table1.datetime1 DESC, table2.datetime2 DESC
```

Desired data:
from table 2 id: 2, 1,
from table 1 id: 3, 2, 1
So: 2, 1, 3, 2, 1

////EDIT

To people who could be struggling with long and complex MySQL request, please try it in PhpmyAdmin! It will tell you the error!

////EDIT

Comment: Why do you have a cartesian product there? Is it intentionally?

Comment: Question has been edited.

Comment: Please provide the desired result based on your sample data.

Comment: Desired result has been added to question.

Comment: SQL returns from 0 to many rows. Your query has multiple columns. Please provide the result that includes all the columns for each returned row..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you really need to do is to consider your schema more carefully. Consider naming the date time columns the same and then running a query like this - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a3b4c/7/0

```
SELECT selection, id, datetimefoo, user FROM (
  SELECT 
    1 AS selection, 
    table1.id, table1.datetimefoo, 
    table3.user 
    FROM table1 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 
    ON table1.id = table2.table1id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table3
    ON table1.id = table3.id


  UNION

  SELECT 
    2 AS selection, 
    table1.id, table1.datetimefoo, 
    table3.user 
    FROM table1 
    INNER JOIN table2 
    ON table1.id = table2.table1id
    INNER JOIN table3
    ON table1.id = table3.id

  ) AS T2
ORDER BY datetimefoo DESC
```

In the SQL fiddle this produces the results closer to what you're looking for. I am still not sure why you need the INNER JOINS on the second query though - there is nothing that you're doing here whcih requires them.

Here is another method that does not require a changing of the column names, but requires an alias for the sortable columns - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ec4bc/3/0

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT 
    1 AS selection, 
    table1.id, table1.datetimefoo AS sort_date, -- alias on first table's date
    table2.datetimebar,
    table3.user 
    FROM table1 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 
    ON table1.id = table2.table1id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table3
    ON table1.id = table3.id


  UNION

  SELECT 
    2 AS selection, 
    table1.id, table1.datetimefoo,
    table2.datetimebar AS sort_date, -- alias on second table's date
    table3.user 
    FROM table1 
    INNER JOIN table2 
    ON table1.id = table2.table1id
    INNER JOIN table3
    ON table1.id = table3.id

  ) AS T2
ORDER BY sort_date DESC
```

Comment: From the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) with my emphasis: "use of ORDER BY for individual SELECT statements implies nothing about the order in which the rows appear in the final result because UNION by default produces an **unordered** set of rows. ... If ORDER BY appears without LIMIT in a SELECT, it is optimized away because it **will have no effect anyway**."

Comment: True @PM77-1, but it works more often than not. I have updated my answer to a much more robust solution.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are over-complicating a rather straight-forward task:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS selection, table1.id as id, table1.datetime1 as date FROM Table1 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS selection, table2.id as id, table2.datetime2 as date FROM Table2 
) AS query
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Comment: @user1824508: then you need to be more accurate with it. You at least need to specify the join condition

Comment: What *other data*? If you have additional requirements, add them to your post. As it's shown now you do not have anything to form a join condition.

Comment: Still not clear what you are trying to achieve. Describe your task.
Identify Primary and Secondary keys.